# Magento 2 Same Coupon code with different Actions

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes

I am having 3 types of Category C1,C2 and C3. In every category there are products.

1) C1 has P1,P2 and P3 (Each P cost $38)

2) C2 has P4, P5 and P6 (Each P cost $58)

3) C3 has P7 and P8 (Each P cost $75)

The rule should be like If Cart item is of C1 then $10, C2 then $20 and C3 is $30.

Now if i add P2,P3, P4 and P8 then the total cost will be $209

But when i applied a coupon it should be $70.

How can i add multiple action for a single coupon code?

Comment: That is going to be difficult to achieve. Why not different coupon?

Comment: No different coupon. Same coupon

Comment: What's the reason for not using a different coupon? If we understand why there might be an alternative solution. As it stands what you are trying to do is impossible with vanilla magento. There may be an extension which let's you do it which more rule builder options or allow duplicate code but I cant think of one. I'm not even sure how you would market the same coupon which offers different levels of discount depending on which product is applied. Typically a coupon has a single discount amount whether that is fixed or percentage. You want a different amount you use a different coupon.

Comment: This is the requirement.

Comment: Sorry can't help you. Good luck!

Comment: Ok can you tell me in UI component how can i add [Add more] Button so textboxes keep added after clicking.